# How to export crystal report into Excel 8.0?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, export-to-excel

I want to export crystal report into excel, but when it exported some of excel column is merged. when i tried exported using the designer with export option is Excel 8.0 it look good. is there any parameter on .Net that i can used to export crystal report to certain excel version?

```
ExportOptions exportOpts = new ExportOptions(); 
ExcelFormatOptions excelFormatOpts = new ExcelFormatOptions (); 
DiskFileDestinationOptions diskOpts = new DiskFileDestinationOptions(); 
exportOpts = Report.ExportOptions; 


excelFormatOpts.ExcelUseConstantColumnWidth = true; 
exportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.Excel; 
exportOpts.FormatOptions = excelFormatOpts; 


exportOpts.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile; 
diskOpts.DiskFileName = fileName; 
exportOpts.DestinationOptions = diskOpts; 

Report.Export ();
```

is there any option that i can add to set the excel version?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ExcelRecord instead Excel because Excel only Export Report with design

```
                ExportOptions exp = new ExportOptions();
                DiskFileDestinationOptions dis = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
                ExcelFormatOptions exexl = new ExcelFormatOptions();                   
                dis.DiskFileName = filename;
                exp = report.ExportOptions;
                exp.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                exp.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.ExcelRecord;
                exp.ExportFormatOptions = exexl;
                exp.ExportDestinationOptions = dis;
                report.Export();
```

Result like :
[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer, but my client want to display the header too. i cant use excel record

Comment: You can display header when use Excel Record but without design, I added picture as example when use Excel Record.

Comment: sorry, what i mean by header is some text above the table not table header, there are titles and some information that needed by client, i want to display it,